# Firewalld Error while install steam on RHEL7

Tags: linux, firewall, redhat, rhel7, firewalld

I run:

```
sudo yum install steam
```

then I got this error:

```
file /usr/lib/firewalld/services/steam-streaming.xml from install of steam-1.0.0.61-2.el7.i686 conflicts with file from package firewalld-0.6.3-2.el7.noarch
```

The only solution that I found was removing firewalld but I dont want to do that.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/356 was useless as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because the `/usr/lib/firewalld/services/steam-streaming.xml` file from the steam package is trying to replace an existing file from the `firewalld` package.

Where is the steam package downloaded from? When I look at the latest Fedora package for steam at https://fedora.pkgs.org/rawhide/rpmfusion-nonfree-x86_64/steam-1.0.0.61-3.fc31.i686.rpm.html, it does not contain the `steam-treaming.xml` file.

An earlier release has this comment

> 2019-01-18 - Simone Caronni  - 1.0.0.59-5
>   - Firewall definitions already bundled in firewalld 0.6.2 on Fedora 29+.
>   - Update firewall definitions to align with Fedora 29+.

If you are sure of what you are doing:

1. Make a backup of `/usr/lib/firewalld/services/steam-streaming.xml`
2. Download the RPM package for steam
3. Install while replacing file

   `sudo rpm -ivh --replacefiles steam-1.0.0.61-3.fc31.i686.rpm`

Comment: Thanks it works now.